# CheckBox and RadioButton not visible

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

After changing "Target Windows Phone OS Version" from Windows Phone 7 to Windows Phone OS 8.0 CheckBox'es and RadioButton's are not visible on devices with Windows Phone 8.0. On devices with Windows Phone 8.1 everything is OK. How to solve that?

Comment: You misunderstand me. I had 7.5 before and changed target to 8.0. After that on 8.0 CheckBox's and RadioButton's are invisible but on 8.1 everything is OK.

Comment: I encountered similar problem. Checkboxes were invisible (but functional) on WP 8.0. Didn't find solution.

Comment: Did you try adding a custom style to the CheckBox and RadioButton. It may be that the Default styling of the elements on WP7.5 might not be visible in WP8

Answer (score 0):

Does the problem occur when you add new Check Boxes or Radio Buttons to your pages? Microsoft did some changes to those controls in WP 8.0 mainly in the terms of colors (brushes)

Try to set some colors to brushes shown here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709910.aspx

Fox example:

```
((SolidColorBrush)App.Current.Resources["CheckBoxBackgroundThemeBrush"]).Color = Colors.Magenta;
```